# Facbook4j: Automatically authenticate a user

Tags: facebook, facebook4j

What I've done so far:

I wanted to add facebook support to my native Java application (Java Web Start application). To get a valid access token for a new user, I forward the user to a web page where he can do the authentication (I don't think there is way doing the authentication directly from the native Java application because I don't use SWT to embed a browser). I'm saving the access token and now I have access from my native Java application to facebook.

The problem:

When the access token expires or becomes invalid for any reason, I have to repeat the whole proces to get a new, valid token. Isn't there a way to get a new access token silently, without user interaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, there is not. User access tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days – after that, you have to send the user through the login flow again to acquire a fresh token.

Comment: Hm. Why is this possible for iOs/Android Apps, but not for others?